# Change PHP working directory, PostgreSQL not working on Windows

Tags: php, postgresql, windows-7

I don't use the Microsoft dump-everything-folder because I like to keep my stuff organized. My PHP and corresponding `php.ini` file are located here...

> C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\PHP 5.6.2 x64\php.ini

PHP does not see PostgreSQL which I've verified via `phpinfo`. The Apache error log showed the following error...

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\php\\php_pgsql.dll'
 - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

So my question is where is the setting to change the default PHP directory? This should get PostgreSQL to work with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the default php extension directory by editing the `php.ini`:

```
extension_dir="FULL_MODIFIED_EXTENSTION_PATH"
```

Something like:

```
extension_dir="C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAPP\PHP 5.6.2 x64\ext"
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/fr/install.windows.extensions.php)

Comment: WORKED! Thank you very much, I'll accept it after the timer expires. +1 for source.